# Стрелочная функция в массиве

Tags: javascript

Этот код работает правильно.

```js
let vasya = { name: "Вася", surname: "Пупкин", id: 1 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", surname: "Иванов", id: 2 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", surname: "Петрова", id: 3 };

let users = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

let usersMapped = users.map(user => ({
  fullName: `${user.name} ${user.surname}`,
  id: user.id
}));

alert( usersMapped[0].id );
alert( usersMapped[0].fullName );
```

Но здесь я решил раскрыть стрелочную функцию,

дабы лучше понять код.

Но где-то я допустил ошибку, подскажите, где она?

```js
let vasya = { name: "Вася", surname: "Пупкин", id: 1 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", surname: "Иванов", id: 2 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", surname: "Петрова", id: 3 };

let users = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

let usersMapped = users.map(function(user){   // Раскрытие стрелочной функции
return fullName: `${user.name} ${user.surname}`,id: user.id;
});


alert( usersMapped[0].id ) 
alert( usersMapped[0].fullName )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли вернуть объект.

```js
let vasya = { name: "Вася", surname: "Пупкин", id: 1 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", surname: "Иванов", id: 2 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", surname: "Петрова", id: 3 };

let users = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

let usersMapped = users.map(function(user) { 
    return {
        fullName: `${user.name} ${user.surname}`, 
        id: user.id
    };
});


alert( usersMapped[0].id ) 
alert( usersMapped[0].fullName )
```

---

Было:

```
return fullName: `${user.name} ${user.surname}`,id: user.id;
```

Стало:

```
return { // <---
    fullName: `${user.name} ${user.surname}`, 
    id: user.id
}; // <---
```

Comment: Благодарю, а я все голову ломаю)

Comment: Не могли бы вы пожалуйста еще раз помочь нубу.
Fullname это добавление  объекта в массиве состоящий из user.name и user.surname?

Comment: `fullName` - это ключ в объекте)) Значение которого да, состоит из имени и фамилии)

Comment: @Человек если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку)

Comment: Ответ очень помог, а где можно почитать про ключи в объектах?

Comment: @Человек скорее вам надо посмотреть про шаблонные строки (https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string), потому что вас, возможно, смутило как произошёл fullname. А так, почитать про объекты надо: https://learn.javascript.ru/object